# Incorrect rendering of text due to letterSpacing in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a problem with letterSpacing in Compose.
When I set TextAlign.End, TextOverflow.Ellipsis and style with letterSpacing text gets cut off.
How can I fix this?

code:

```
val textStyleWithoutLetterSpacing = TextStyle()
val textStyleWithLetterSpacing = TextStyle(letterSpacing = 1.sp)

@Composable
fun Sample() {
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
            style = textStyleWithoutLetterSpacing
        )
        Text(
            text = "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
            style = textStyleWithLetterSpacing
        )
    }
}
```

result:
[image: 1]

Comment: seems like it is a problem with the compose itself, check this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228463206?pli=1)

Comment: Adding any modifiers, like wrapping modifiers, or anything that might constraint the size of the text? Is it being manually measured inside a `Layout`?

Comment: No. The example code produces this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue which I believe has to do with combining `textAlign = TextAlign.End` with `overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis`. I have just had a play with you sample and came up with this (which is similar to how I solved my problem):

```
val textStyleWithoutLetterSpacing = TextStyle()
val textStyleWithLetterSpacing = TextStyle(letterSpacing = 1.sp)

@Composable
fun Sample() {
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
            style = textStyleWithoutLetterSpacing
        )

        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd) {
            Text(
                text = "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890",
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1,
                style = textStyleWithLetterSpacing
            )
        }
    }
}
```

In essence, I delegated the alignment of the text to the `Box` component and that seems to bypass the bug in the compose library (v1.2.1 at the time of writing this answer).